# Categorical formulation of linear transformations between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, category-theory

My question regards the formulation of linear transformations between vector spaces as morphisms in an appropriate category.
I know that any biproduct category admits a calculus of matrix. What I'm wondering is whether we can describe a linear transformation through the individual action of each element of the corresponding matrix. For example, would it be possible to describe an element of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with this diagram, wherein the objects are 1-dimensional vector spaces ?
[image: matrix]

I've tried to see if the usual matrix multiplication relation holds, but this would require adding more relations, and it seems to lead to contradictions. Has this been studied before ?

Comment: What further relations do you think you'd have to add?

Comment: @KevinCarlson: if one tries to compose two diagrams like the one pictured above, then some relations must be added to recover the usual matrix multiplication law. But so far, I haven't been able to figure which one, as many lead to contradictions. Or maybe this is just a stupid idea....

Comment: No, I asked which ones-I don't see how you actually need any. That you don't seems to be the point of the matrix calculus for biproduct categories to me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this ? If the diagram in the question is valid, I really don't see how we recover matrix multiplication from the composition of two such diagrams...

Comment: I don't have a latex package for drawing such diagrams, so let's see if I can do it with words. Attach another diagram below your first with labels $e,f,g,h$. The composition has as leftmost label the sum of all paths from the left input string to the left output. Such paths are left-left, ie ea and right-left, ie fc, so the composed diagram has leftmost entry ea+fc, just as it should.  You can check the other three entries in the same way. Maybe the confusion lay in the notion "sum over all paths," so I suppose we do have to add the definition of that convention for composing string diagrams.